# What does "\uf8ff" mean in java?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8

Been searching for it everywhere but couldn't find the answer to that.
If I am not mistaken it must have something to do with "utf-8", but still have no clue what it is.

Answer (score 5):

**"\uf8ff"** is actually a Java unicode Escape character. This is commonly called **<Private Use, Last>**

The general form of the escape characters are:

**"\u{0000-FFFF}"** -> Unicode [Basic Multilingual Plane only, see below] hex value 
                  does not handle unicode values higher than 0xFFFF (65535),
                  the high surrogate has to be separate: \uD852\uDF62
                  Four hex characters only (no variable width)

Escape characters are always preceded with "\" and used to perform some specific task like go to next line etc.

For more Details on Escape Character Refer following link:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html